# How to change the opacity of a plotly polygon or ribbon in R?

Tags: r, plotly

In plotly for R there is an opacity argument for lines and markers, but how do I change the opacity of fill colours in `add_ribbons` and `add_polygons`?

e.g. `opacity = 0` makes the line disappear here:

```
plot_ly() %>% add_lines(x = 1:4, y = 1:4, color = I("red"), opacity = 0)
```

but has no effect on the polygon here:

```
plot_ly() %>% add_polygons(x = c(1, 1, 2, 2), y = c(1, 2, 2, 1), 
                           color = I("red"), opacity = 0)
```

Using `alpha` doesn't work either. How can I change the opacity of fill colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative you could try using `fillColor` and `rgba` color (last digit being alpha):

```
%>% add_polygons(fillcolor = 'rgba(7, 164, 181, 1)')
```

vs

```
%>% add_polygons(fillcolor = 'rgba(7, 164, 181, 0.2)')
```

Just adjust the numbers for the colour you want.

Comment: Thanks! And even easier with toRGB("red",alpha=1).